# Hibernate JPA columnDefinition serial not generating

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I'm using PostgreSQL and I need to have one column generated with sequence ID. But it's not a primary key so I can't use `@Id` annotation. I don't want to create another entity for the sequence.
Here's the column

```
@Column(name="sequence_id", columnDefinition="serial")
private int sequenceId
```

and this is how I added the column to the database

```
ALTER TABLE items ADD COLUMN sequece_id SERIAL
```

Above solution didn't work at all and the value of that column is always 0
What should I do to just to make a column whose value is auto incremented but not a primary key

Answer (score 4):

You need to add Hibernate `@Generated` annotation to the column field

```
@Column(name="sequence_id", columnDefinition="serial")
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
private int sequenceId
```

Comment: great it works! What if I would to costomize the serial.. for example start the serial from 1000.